# Не отображается Кириллица (кодировка Windows -1251) на GitHub

Tags: github

Магия, создал два файла разница в одну строку, но в первом случае с кодировкой в файле на гитхабе все нормально, а во втором случае где код длинней всего на одну строку кириллица уже не отображается.
В чем может быть причина такого поведения?

Вот файлы:
1. [Correct](https://github.com/anklav24/123/blob/master/Create-New-GitHub-Repositories-From-API-Correct.bat)
2. [Incorrect](https://github.com/anklav24/123/blob/master/Create-New-GitHub-Repositories-From-API-Incorrect.bat)

Comment: Странно, что Correct вообще отобразился, ведь гитхаб по идее ничего не знает о кодировках файлов. Тем не менее, корректный файл определяется гитхабом как windows-1251, некорректный как windows-1252, почему — непонятно